# Jquery Jcrop - getting (and setting) all co-ords from all crops

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I've got a jcrop instance where I'm asking the user to make 2 crops (a portrait and a landscape FYi)

I've got the cropping all working, but getting the co-ords out for both is a pain... When I update one it becomes the 1st. Here's my code:

```
$('#myimage').Jcrop({
                setSelect   : [ 100, 100, 300, 150 ],
                bgOpacity   : 0.4,
                multi       : true,
                multiMax    : 2,
                onSelect    :setCoordinates,
                boxWidth    : 1000,
                boxHeight   : 600
            }, function(){
                jcrop_api = this;
            });
```

And here's my setCooirdinates function:

```
function setCoordinates(c) {
  console.log( c );
}
```

All that's logging is the currently selected item. I want to get the two crop boxes so I can assign those vars to hidden fields on my form for sending to the server for post-processing. c just returns x/y etc for the current item.. I want them both!

Is there a way in jcrop to say 'get me all current crop data?'

:)

Comment: Hmm, I still can't get this.. I think a better question would be, if I have 3 selection areas, is there a method on jcrop to get all x/y info for them with a single call?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an addition function to eh master jcrop file that counts the crops, and returns them. I used unscale to account for the fact my canvas is scaled over a shrunk image

```
getMulti: function(){
  var count;
  var countCrops = this.ui.multi.length;
  var returnMulti= [];
    for(count = 0; count < countCrops; count++) {
        returnMulti = returnMulti.concat(this.unscale(this.ui.multi[count].last))
    }
    return returnMulti;
},
```

And this gets an array of the two crops... it does error on the first one as there is not a 2nd.. but I don't care (well, I do, I'll clean it later)